# How to find first table in XML document using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to find first table in xml document. I have mentioned example below.

Input

```
<doc>
    <first>
        <table-cover>
            <table>
                <thead>Table1</thead>
                <tbody>Table1</tbody>
            </table>
        </table-cover>
    </first>
    <first>
        <second>
            <table-cover>
                <table>
                    <thead>Table2</thead>
                    <tbody>Table2</tbody>
                </table>
        </table-cover>
        </second>
    </first>
    <first>
        <table-cover>
            <table>
                <thead>Table3</thead>
                <tbody>Table3</tbody>
            </table>
        </table-cover>
    </first>
</doc>
```

I want to add special element called `<first-table>` for first table in the document

Tried template:

```
<xsl:template match="table-cover">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="table/position() eq 1">
            <!-- code -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- code -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

But when I use above template all tables are selected and apply condition for all tables. I want to apply `<xsl:when test="table/position() eq 1">` to only first table.

How can I fix this problem by changing `<xsl:when test="??????">`

I am using `XSLT 2.0`. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether a `table` is the first table in the document with

```
test="empty(table/preceding::table)"
```

I would use two template rules here, rather than xsl:choose.

If the document is large, then testing each table to see whether there are any earlier tables is inefficient. A faster approach is to bind a global variable to the first table:

```
<xsl:variable name="first-table" select="(//table)[1]"/>
```

and then test subsequent tables against this variable:

```
<xsl:template match="table[. is $first-table]">...
```